# Odds of drawing the same ball in consecutive rounds

Tags: probability

Consider a game where $k$ out of $N$ numbered, distinct balls with labels $1$, $2$, ..., $N$. How high is the probability that one or more numbers are repeatedly drawn in two consecutive rounds? More generally, what is the probability for $r$ rounds?

I suspect that this is related to the birthday problem, but if I understand it correctly, that problem only deals with collisions within a single round where repetitions are allowed.

Comment: Do you want the probability that a particular ball (like $7$) is drawn twice? Or the probability that exactly one ball is drawn twice? Or the probability that at least one ball is drawn twice?

Comment: I am interested in the probability that at least one ball is drawn twice (e.g. $((1,3,5),(2,3,6))$ counts as a "collision event", as does $((1,2,3),(2,3,4))$.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by 'from $[0,N]$'?

Comment: @drhab: Each ball in the urn has a number between $0$ and $N$; there are exactly $N$ balls, and each number occurs exactly once.

Comment: If there are $N$ balls then I would make it: '..with labels $1,\dots,N$'. Just to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that a certain set of balls has been drawn in the first round. We find the probability of no overlap in the second round. There are $\binom{N}{k}$ equally likely ways to draw $k$ balls in the second round. The number of no overlap ways is $\binom{N-k}{k}$. For the probability of **no** overlap, divide.

**Remarks:** $1.$ If $a\lt b$, the binomial coefficient $\binom{a}{b}$ is defined to be $0$.

$2.$ The notion of odds is seldom used in probability theory. For a rough translation into the language of odds, if the probability of an event is $p$, then the odds for the event are $p:1-p$.

Comment: Thanks, I had not seen the edit, what I saw said something like labelled from $0$ to $N$.

Comment: Yes me too. I was suspicious and gave him some advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

What is the probability that **no** number is drawn twice in $2$ consecutive rounds?